# R TM Package stemDocument. What dictionary does it use

Tags: r, tm

My version of R is 3.4.1 platform x86_64-w64_mingw32/x64

I am using R to find the most popular words in a document. 
I would like to stem the words and then Complete them. This means I need to use the SAME dictionary for both the stemming and the completion. I am confused by the TM package I am using.

Q1) The stemDocument function seems to work fine without a dictionary defined explicitly. However I would like to define one or at least get hold of the one it uses if it is inbuilt into R. Can I download it anywhere? *Apparently I cannot do this*

```
dfCorpus <- tm_map(dfCorpus, stemDocument, language = "english")
```

Q2) I would like to use the SAME dictionary to complete the words and if they aren't in the dictionary keep the original. *Can't do this* so just need to know what format the dictionary should be in to work because it currently just giving me NA for all the answers. It is two columns stem and word. This is just an example I found online.

```
dict.data = fread("Z:/Learning/lemmatization-en.txt")
```

I'm expecting the code to be something like

```
dfCorpus <- stemCompletion_modified(dfCorpus, dictionary="dict.data", type="prevalent")`
```

thanks
Edit. I see that I am trying to solve my problem with a hammer. Just because documentation says to do it one way I was trying to get it to work. So now what I need is just a lookup between all English words and their base not stem. I know I'm not allowed to ask that here but I'm sure I will find it. Have a good weekend.

Comment: Stemming does not require a dictionary. `stemCompletetion` requires a `dictionary` otherwise you only get stems back. Please take a look at the documentation.

Comment: The dictionary needs to be another Corpus as per the documentation. The easiest thing to do is save a copy of your corpus before stemming e.g. `dict.corpus <- dfCorpus` and then use that in `stemCompletion`.

Comment: What do you mean by **base** not **stem**? If your document is stemmed it is unclear to me how having the base help you with stem completion?